# Remove got to current queue button in android auto for exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-auto

I am using [UniversalMusicPlayer](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/tree/master) as base for create my project.

I want to remove all the controllers from playing screen of Android Auto except play/pause.

In [this file](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/example/android/uamp/media/MusicService.kt), i have override function in class `UampQueueNavigator` called `getSupportedQueueNavigatorActions` and `return 0`

I have to override a function in class `UampQueueNavigator`:

```
   override fun getSupportedQueueNavigatorActions(player: Player?): Long {
        return 0
    }
```

That override function disabled next/previous button but not left most current queue button. [Reference image](https://ibb.co/c1jjKPR). And if i don't set `setQueueNavigator`, than it will do not display metadata description on playing screen of Android Auto [just like](https://ibb.co/0hntdZZ)